# Flutter the type 'Function' can't assign to parameter type 'void'

Tags: flutter

The Error says,

The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(bool?)?'.

like this. How can I fix this ?

My code is

[image: 1]

Comment: `toggleCheckboxState` should take a boolean as an argument and return void.

Comment: The question is badly formated with reference image

Comment: I would suggest keeping this in the same build method rather than making a new class for the checkbox it would prevent a lot of unnecessary data from passing into the widget tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a minor change required at line 34 replace the syntax with this `final void Function(bool?) toogleCheckboxState;`
and if using null safety at line 24 add a null check